# Do require restart dmgr manager after changed value properties of object on websphere?

Tags: websphere

Cause I'm operating Live system based on Websphere Network deployment version.

Sometimes I have adjust value such as Mail session username/ password , JVM min max heapsize.

Most common tasks, I usually restart both dmgr manager, node agent, cluster to apply changed value.

Could anybody confirm that, If I have changed value, just only require dmgr manager is enough, no need to restart node agent -> It is important because restart dmgr manager not impact to application's running state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting everything is safest, otherwise it depends on knowing about what you've changed.  For example, if you change a jvm property on the app servers, then you only need to restart the app servers.  You only need to restart the dmgr if you changed something that affects it.  It's not always easy to know, so if in doubt, restart everything.

Comment: Thank bruce T. I understand it, restarting everything from node agent to dmgr manager sure to work, and safest. But our systems are providing service online, and many services  , app runs on it, so each time restart , it has been taken lots time to start and services back to serve. So If could be, restarting dmgr manager doesn't impact to service online. I  googled much, but stills can't find any official info about this concerned.

Comment: If you're running a cluster, I think you can quiesce each cluster member then restart it one at a time, then finally restart the node agents and the dmgr.  That way there should always be a server available to take requests.

Comment: yes, I often stop and restart sequence member of cluster to ensure server available to get requests, and most traffic auto switching to other nodes. However sometimes it makes 01 server run higher than others, although when node server come back, and this issue lead to hung thread -> I have to restart all cluster. Is it the issue of WAS ?

Comment: A hung thread alarm doesn't always indicate a problem, sometimes they go away by themselves when whatever was blocking them goes away (for example, the node agent comes back up.).  If they go on for a long time, or there are a lot of them, it might be a concern.  Taking a thread dump will show what the "hung" threads are trying to do.  Support can look at these and frequently suggest tuning.